# Allow the return of a 404 for a (validly) missing robots.txt in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, robots.txt

I was reading the Google documentation on robots.txt and found that they will delay indexing your site unless they get a 404 or 200 response:

> Before Googlebot crawls your site, it accesses your robots.txt file to
>   determine if your site is blocking Google from crawling any pages or
>   URLs. If your robots.txt file exists but is unreachable (in other
>   words, if it doesn’t return a 200 or 404 HTTP status code), we’ll
>   postpone our crawl rather than risk crawling disallowed URLs.

On my site I am using web.xml error codes to map error codes to a Spring MVC controller method:

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/showerror</location>
</error-page>
```

This will forward to an error page which returns 200 (but an HTML page).

When the URL requested is robots.txt I actually want the 404 to be returned un-handled. Is there an easy way to exempt a specific URL (/robots.txt) from this error handling?

Of course the other option is to return an empty robots.txt which doesn't block anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach I would probably use would be to actually handle it in a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RobotsTxtController {
    @RequestMapping("/robots.txt")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public void robotsTxt() {}
}
```

You could have the method return a view name if you want an actual page to appear.

This way, it's an actual "page" and not handled by your normal 404 process, but the `@ResponseStatus` makes it return as a 404.